# Do not stop Gradle build after first failed task

Tags: gradle

In certain conditions I would like my Gradle build to not stop after the first task fails.
I would like to see all failed tasks.

I found the gradle command-line option --continue
But, I would like more programmatic control.

I looked for an exception I could throw which would mark a task as failed but will continue the build (other tasks which do not depend on the failed task).
I could not find such an exception.

I looked for ways to emulate the --continue command line option dynamically or for specific tasks, again - could not find a way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

Use method [StartParameter.setContinueOnFailure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#setContinueOnFailure-boolean-)

Example of use in build script:

```
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

Use method [StartParameter.isContinueOnFailure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#isContinueOnFailure--) to query the value.